# How can I write unit test for azure function which has run method with parameter?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

How can write unit test for azure function which has below given code sample.

```
[FunctionName("DemoScheduler")]
 public static async void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5* * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
 {

   Implementation is there...    

 }
```

Comment: we manage this by putting our implementations into "Handlers" which are tested. The Run-Logic does nothing but calling the handler.

Comment: As @cyptus said, but what is stopping you just calling this method? You can create your own instance of a `TimerInfo`, and switch from using `TraceWriter` to the newer `ILogger` interface that you can easily mock.

Comment: I created own instance of a TimerInfo, and TraceWriter to the newer ILogger interface that can easily mock. but  while adding reference of azure function in unit test project its throws error.

Comment: If you don't tell us the error, how can we help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @cyptus said you can just use a separate class for the test.

```
[FunctionName("DemoScheduler")]
public static async void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5* * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
    new Runner().Run(myTimer, log);
 }

 public class Runner 
 {
    public void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log) 
    {
        // your code    
    }   
 }

 [TestClass]
 public class RunnerTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Run_ShouldWorkCorrectly()
    {
        var timerInfo = new TimerInfo();
        //Configure your timer here

        new Runner().Run(timerInfo, new StubLogger());

        //your test
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll going to implement things & Let you know. Its working or not.

Comment: you can also get the runner by DI `ctor(Runner runner)` to obtain other services